# How to get form-field values on html-file where form was send

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html-file containing a form (start.html). Submitting it, navigates to a different html-form (result.html).

How do I get date-entries in result.html done in textfields of form in start.html?

Something like:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var fww = 'what to do to get value fieldsindex.html?';
            $('#Div1').html(fww);
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="Div1">

</div>
```

Any solution with JQuery or Javascript is appreciated. thanks

Comment: is there a specific reason this can't be done with the server side scriot that process the form as is typically done?

Answer (score 1):

you can get the form data using form Elements id as shown below, 
but you can not transfer the data from one form to other form using JS only, you should use some backend controller

form.html

```
<input type="text" id="formElement">
```

Js

```
$("formElement").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in plain JS/jQuery, you would have to:

1. Get all your form values, store them in a json object.
2. Save them into a sessionStorage (will be destroyed, when you will
   close the browser tab)
3. On page load read values from session storage and use some kind of templating plugin (Handelbar, SammyTemplates) to generate inputs with values from first form.

But a better solution would be to generate this on backend. I would advise to go with second option, and in result page generate wanted HTML, willed with correct values.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the server side, you can use HTML5 local storage or you can use a more universal solution: cookies, the jQuery plug-in is quite useful: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/.

Just a quick tip: when you use cookies, you should make it valid across entire site:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

NB: Keep in mind that saving the data on the client browser is not very secure and can be easily modified using Firebug or what ever else !